# Fast calculation of sum of absolute difference with Integral Image

Tags: image-processing

I am trying to find the fast way of block matching between 2 images and I am using sum of absolute difference (SAD) as similarity metric.

Given a reference block A at NxN size in frame 1, a full search for the best matched block within  a search window of size (2W+N)*(2W+N) in frame 2, where W stands for the maximum allowed displacement. Full search block matching requires (2W+1)^2 comparison.

Integral image can calculate the sum of pixels in a block in any image quickly but I could not work out how to calculate the sum of absolute difference (SAD) here.

Is it possible to use the integral image to calculate SAD here? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think computing an integral image (of what?) can help you here.

Comment: I can't see how calculating summed area tables (i.e. integral images) will help in computing SADs between two blocks / images.